# Html Email - Set priority on

Tags: html, css, html-email

```
   <table width="100%;">
      <tr>
         <td>  <!--Right Space (Variable Width)-->  </td>
         <td>  <!--content (Width Set - High Priority)-->  </td>
         <td>  <!--Left Space (Variable Width -->  </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

I am having a problem with coding emails where I want margins to be different based on screen size.  It works fine with media queries but i've realized that there are some email clients that don't support them.  I've also tried using width percentages but I want the content to be about 90% on a mobile sized screen and about 50% on a larger screen.  I am using tables and empty table cells to create my margins and can only use inline styling.

I want to know if there is a way to set css properties so that when the screen width decreases the content cell has the highest priority for it's size and the left and right 'margins' will be the ones to decrease in width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a use case for max-width.  You can set the default width of the element to 90%, but define a max width that is half of your total desktop display width.  You would also need to include MSO conditional due to Outlook's lack of support for this attribute. [CSS (for HTML email) reference guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

See below:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table align="center" width="640"><tr><td align="center"><![endif]-->
<table align="center" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;">
<tr>
<td align="center">
   <!--[if (gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table width="320" align="center"><tr><td align="center"><![endif]-->
   <table width="90%" align="center" style="max-width:320px;">
   <tr>
   <td align="center">This content will be at 90% width of the container up to 320px wide, where it will stop</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   <!--[if (gte mso 9) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

As my experience,email clients are allows only inline-style.

According to your requirement,you need to set below the codes,

```
<div><!--email client body-->

   <table width="650px;padding:50px;"><!--you can give padding not only margin properties of CSS-->
      <table style="width:100%">
            <!--content-->
              <table style="padding:20px"></table><!--Again added to padding instead of margin--->
      </table>

   </table>

</div>
```

**Note**: Email mobile application only support the swing the contents in email.If you open email in browser not swing the all contends.